# Installing Python BeautifulSoup package with Homebrew on macOS

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, homebrew

I installed Python on my macOS using Homebrew. Now, I'm attempting to use `BeautifulSoup`, so I executed the following command: `brew install python-beautifulsoup4`. However, I encountered a message stating, 'Warning: No available formula with the name `python-beautifulsoup4`.

What could be the issue here? How should I properly install and use this Python package?

Comment: You can use pip to install BeautifulSoup for your Python installation. If you installed Python 3.12 you can run the command `python3.12 -m pip install beautifulsoup4`

Comment: Try  this `python3. -m pip install beautifulsoup4`

Comment: by doing that I get: error: externally-managed-environment × This environment is externally managed ╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try brew install xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to install.

Comment: Have you tried using a virtual environment?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `pip` to install BeautifulSoup4 with `pip install beautifulsoup4` or `pip3 install beautifulsoup4`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. When I do that I get:

error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try brew install
    xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.

Comment: @notGeek This is purely a hunch, but is your pip associated with your Python2 from macOS? An externally managed environment error is usually a warning that you are trying to install packages from a pip installer that could break your system from conflicting packages... Try `which pip` to see which pip you are using.